# Preserve static fields between invocations of ant's java task

Tags: java, ant, classloader

Here's the situation: I trying to make a ant test script that does the following
1 - Runs a utility to create test data
2 - Runs junit suite
3 - Runs a utility to clean up test data.

The problems is parts 2 & 3 need to access to some static fields of the utility in 1 (e.g. generated unique names of test data).  This issue I'm having is that it the static fields of the class are null when I try to access them as though the java task in #1 was run in a separate process or using a different classloader (I've tried setting the attribute fork="false" on the java task and using -Dant.reuse.loader=true on the cmd line).  Any ant gurus know what's going on here?

Comment: Why can't the test data get written to a file?

Comment: I suppose it could - it just feels like a huge kludge for every single test to have to read the data from disk when it seems like there should be a way to keep it in memory

Comment: I suppose each `java` task will get at least a separate class loader. Can't you put all of these actions in a single `java` call (by writing a new class with a main method which includes these calls)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with different class loaders, you'll never get past one's class loader finding the "wrong" instance of the exact same class and hence using the "wrong" static value.  You need to do the communications between the ant invocations via a file.  A temporary file will likely not do, as it will likely be removed before the second set of ant classes get a chance to work with it.

There are two issues, the generation of suitable property values, and the transmission of them between ant calls.  Perhaps you don't need all of this since your situation might already generate suitable identifiers, but it's here if you do.

To generate suitable values, one ant process should the propertyfile task to generate the appropriate names, with the per-run changing identifier as part of the name

```
<propertyfile file="testConfig.properties.ids" comment="Machine generated file, do not edit!">
  <entry key="test.suite.1.id" type="int" operation="+" unit="1"/>
  <entry key="test.suite.2.id" type="int" operation="+" unit="1"/>
</propertyfile>
<properties file="testConfig.properties.ids"/>
<propertyfile file="testConfig.properties" comment="Machine generated file, do not edit!">
  <entry key="test.suite.1.name" type="string" operation="=" value="TestSuite${test.suite.1.id}.sh"/>
  <entry key="test.suite.2.name" type="string" operation="=" value="TestSuite${test.suite.2.id}.sh"/>
</propertyfile>
```

Subsequent ant processes can then just source in the original ant process's generated property file.

```
<property file="testConfig.properties"/>
```

Which will have the effect of defining

```
test.suite.1.name=TestSuite34.sh
test.suite.2.name=TestSuite83.sh
```

Comment: I take it there's no way to make ant use the same classloader then?  I guess thinking about it in retrospect it makes sense since each java task gets to define it's own classpath they have to use separate classloaders.